# How to pick the nearest GPS Value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to java and I'm trying some stuff on jQuery mobile. I can get the current GPS location and I have array/json with a list of location information. How do you check the nearest location from the array/json agents my current location. If I do a "IF" statement the current location has to be exactly the same as on the array/json which is almost impossible  if your moving.

Comment: which is it an array or Json? they're pretty different?

Comment: First, Java =/= JavaScript. Second, do you have some code example please?

Comment: yes please read the [faq] and [about] to help you format your question better

Comment: I have list of locations on json a file which I can import to a array. Sorry I should have mentioned this.

Comment: Maybe this link could be helpful for you: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Thats pretty awesome so far, but do you have some code already?